# FallbackResource works for some pages but not others

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using FallbackResource in the .htaccess file:

```
FallbackResource page.php
```

This is the only line I have in this file. When I type

```
www.test.com/test/no-page
```

I get redirected to page.php indeed. So this work (where no-page in this example is a page that of course doesn't exist). And to double check, if I removed FallbackResource from the .htaccess file, then this case doesn't work (I get an Error 500).

Now when I do:

```
www.test.com/test/no-page/no-page-2
```

I get an Error 500?

Is there anything else I need to do, or check? What I need is to have any pages not found being redirected to page.php whatever the URL is.

## EDIT

Also in this question [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php), someone suggests that the syntax should be:

```
FallbackResource /page.php
```

Which is also what they say in the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

In my case, it only works without the /. Could someone shed some light on this as well?